# Why am I getting a date that is not in the interval?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I want to get values in a given interval

```
      const result = await this.chCalendar.find({
      where: {
        time: Between('2021-05-31 00:00:00', '2021-05-31 23:59:59'),
      },
      order: {
        time: "ASC"
      }
    })
```

But I get the first value with date - "2021-05-30T23:00:00.000Z"
When requested directly via apps MySQL Workbench, everything is fine.
MySQL server timezone - Europe/Athens
I tried to set it - cross-env IS_NUXT_DISABLED=true TZ='Europe/Athens' nodemon
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It helps me.

```
@Column({
  type: 'date',
  name: 'time'
})
time: string;
```

Comment: /**
     * Force date types (TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATE) to be returned as strings rather then inflated into JavaScript Date objects.
     * Can be true/false or an array of type names to keep as strings.
     */
    readonly dateStrings?: boolean | string[];